# MongoDB Max, Sort, and Limit

Tags: mongodb

I'm attempting to use find (not aggregation) to give me the max score by student on a test.  Essentially would be a sort by student, find top score for that student, then sort the result set.  Here is the data:

```
 { "_id" : 1, "name" : "Pat", "score" : 97 }
 { "_id" : 1, "name" : "Pat", "score" : 92 }
 { "_id" : 2, "name" : "Pat", "score" : 89 }
 { "_id" : 3, "name" : "Ken", "score" : 91 }
 { "_id" : 4, "name" : "Ken", "score" : 81 }
```

I'm looking for the result to look like this (where only the students top score is returned):

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Pat", "score" : 97 }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Ken", "score" : 91 }
```

I've tried many different combinations but can't get it to work.  I know in SQL how I'd do it.  Here is my current code, which is just sorting it:

```
 db.grades.find().sort({score: -1})
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use:

```
db.grades.find().sort('-score').distinct('name').sort('score')
```

Comment: TypeError: Object DBQuery: mydb.grades -> { "query" : { }, "orderby" : "-score" } has no method 'distinct'

Comment: Not sure why ? MongoDB supports https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

Comment: Looking at the docs, it appears because distinct() isn't inside of a find()

Comment: Are you using mongodb with node.js ? If yes what ODM are you using ?

Comment: > db.version()
2.6.11